# Magento 2: How to display data from the database from the model?

Tags: magento2

In magento 1

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('feedback_id');
$data = Mage::getModel('feedback/block')->load($id);
```

how to access the model and display the data in magento 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 for each model are generated factory classes automatically (unless you create one by yourself what is not needed in most cases). This factories can be injected in the constructor of a block or controller (or other classes). Then you can create an instance of your model and load the needed object by id.

Here is an example for your `feedback` model:

```
protected $feedbackFactory;

//inject the feedback factory in your constructor. 
//Depending what class you are extending or what other object you need you may have some other objects injected here
public function __construct( \Vendor\Module\Model\FeedbackFactory $feedbackFactory) 
{
    $this->feedbackFactory = $feedbackFactory;
}


public function getMyFeedback()
{   
    //in a controller or block accessing $this->getRequest() works in other classes you may use something appropriate
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('feedback_id');
    //create a feedback object
    $feedback = $this->feedbackFactory->create();

    //load the feedback by id
    $feedback->load($id);

    return $feedback;
}
```

If you implement the above code in a block you can use the data in a phtml template like you do in Magento 1.

Here you can find the documentation about factories in Magento 2: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/factories.html